# web browser crashes when using mysql prepared query with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to return the result of query to DB, which I think would be a promise and then consume that promise in another file.Here is my model code (User.js) :

```
User.prototype.login = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?', [this.data.username, this.data.password], (err, attemptedUser) => {
            if (err) {
                pool.release();
               return reject(err);
            } else {
                pool.release();
               return resolve(attemptedUser);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and the code in my controller file (userController.js):

```
const User = require('../models/User');
exports.login = (req, res) => {
let user = new User(req.body);
    user.login()
        .then((result) => {
            res.send(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.send(err);
        });
};
```

But when I click on the login button the page doesn't go to the specified URL and keeps working until crash.
Where is the problem?

**UPDATE-1**
This is my db.js :

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 100
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: why have you added return keywords on resolve and reject btw.

Comment: @AneesIjaz I know that resolve() and reject() would  return a promise but somewhere in stackoverflow I saw the problem was missing the return keyword.

Comment: is there any error on console ? whats the status code for the crashed request ?

Comment: No there isn't any errors.It keeps spinning until crash and says: localhost didn’t send any data.